# Restore a BlobReferenceProperty from db

Tags: google-app-engine, restore, blobstore

I'm having a hard time understanding how to do something stupid.
I have a GAE model like this:

```
class Post(Base):
  img1 = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(blobstore.BlobKey, required=False)
```

this is the method that i used for save the blob key:

```
post.img1 = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key).key()
```

but when i try to restore the blobstore key from db with

```
post = model.Post.getThePostInSomeWay()
blob_key = post.img1
```

the following error is thrown:

File "/Users/piero/Sviluppo/dataplanner/main.py", line 240, in display_post_by_id

```
    blob_key = post.img1
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 604, in __get__
    return getattr(model_instance, self._attr_name())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 756, in _attr_name
    return '_' + self.name
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

note that if i log the whole post object i see the img1 field

```
INFO     2012-07-30 06:54:43,490 main.py:239] Post(key=Key('Post', 31), allow_comments=True, body=u'<p>Test</p>', created_utc=None, img1=datastore_types.BlobKey('YPeUXQSfL_VqwKZITPtk-w=='), title=Test')
```

what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: additional info: if i log type(post) i don't see the img1 field

Comment: The solution is to use in model 
img1 = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=False)
in place of
img1 = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(blobstore.BlobKey, required=False)